# Is there a way with DataFrame objects to grab rows based on single-row conditions AND the preceding rows as well? Like 'grep -B1 ...' does on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pd.DataFrame object df, and i can select some rows, say on a single-column condition, and i can grab all the rows matching the condition, but i wish to also grab the preceding row before each of the rows matching the condition. The result should be a pd.DataFrame with these rows.

I can write code to do that, i am not asking for it (but feel free to illustrate if you think you have a neat + short way of doing it), but i was wondering if pandas doesn't have a built-in tool to do it i am not aware of.

An example showing what i'm looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b':'apples'}, {'a':5, 'b':'pears'}, {'a':2, 'b':'4 plums'},
                   {'a':9, 'b':'bananas'}, {'a':5, 'b':'cherries'}, {'a':2, 'b':'100 grapes'},
                   {'a':3, 'b':'oranges'}, {'a':8, 'b':'cherries'}])
print(df)
# prints:                | my markings here, not part of printout, showing
#    a           b       | with a '+' the rows i wish to select and why
# 0  1      apples       |
# 1  5       pears       | +  - because it's a preceding row
# 2  2     4 plums       | +  - because it has a number
# 3  9     bananas       |
# 4  5    cherries       | +  - because it's a preceding row    
# 5  2  100 grapes       | +  - because it has a number
# 6  3     oranges       |
# 7  8    cherries       |

# condition would be all the rows where 'b' column has the number of items too:
df[[not x.isalpha() for x in df.b]]
# but this returns only the condition rows, of index 2 and 5, not rows
# 1, 2, 4, 5 as i want it.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for `shift(-1)`:

```
c=~df.b.str.isalpha()
df[c|c.shift(-1)]
```

---

```
   a           b
1  5       pears
2  2     4 plums
4  5    cherries
5  2  100 grapes
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, is neat and very short!! 
I see, if i wanted previous 2 rows, i can use your technique as

    c=~df.b.str.isalpha()
    df[c|c.shift(-1)|c.shift(-2)]

but what if i want a larger number of rows? Is there another trick
you can show me to accomplish that, or should i just add the 'or'
conditions for all of them, like:

    df[c|c.shift(-1)|c.shift(-2)|...|c.shift(-20)]

Comment: I meant like in "grep -B n ..." where you ask for preceding n rows, together with each matching row, not the match row and n-th row back. I saw this as a natural extension of the question asked, just in case it has a simple solution too. Anyway, i am happy with your main answer!